# Turning blade 45 degrees - Steton saw

Tags: table-saw

I have a machinery model Steton SC00NC and it has suffered a damage at the mechanism that turns the blade at 45 degrees. I'm sorry I don't know the exact name of the parts (the mechanism is as in the first photo below), but would like to know if somebody has any idea where can i find to buy these items for the model or something that fits?

Thanks!
[image][image]

Comment: This is tricky because any advice about where you can buy stuff is going to be outdated in an internet minute, leaving any Q&A based on it useless for future visitors. Maybe a forum like Reddit would be more helpful, as those sites tend to be a bit more about immediate and temporary info like this. (Having an old table saw myself that needs replacement parts, I feel your pain, though.)

Comment: Would you please share the names of these parts in English since it is hard to also navigate through internet without the exact names? Sorry for the dumb question but I'm not from an English talking country. Thanks!

Comment: You appear to have a "panel saw" and those parts look like some sort of "worm gear" arrangement.

Comment: This collective assembly is often called the "tilt mechanism." The screw would be called the "tilt screw".

Comment: I think the correct names are trunnion gear an trunnion screw.

Answer (score 2):

We can't really help you with any specific vendors that you couldn't find yourself with some internet sleuthing, but one way you can solve this is to find a machinist or metalworker in your area that can repair or recreate suitable parts for you.

What you show is just a worm-gear arrangement of some kind. Depending on the damage, such parts can often be rebuilt or scratch-built quite easily with modern metalworking tools.

This is definitely a case of trading your time (searching for and acquiring parts) for money (paying a tradesperson).

You may be able to find a metalworker in your area with some web search terms or by asking your local union or "maker space". YouTube is, surprisingly, an excellent way to find local tradespeople who might be interested in an easy fix-it project in return for an opportunity for a bite-sized project for a video.

Of course, in a pinch you could [contact Steton directly](https://www.steton.it/en/). Even if they can't sell you new-old-stock parts, they can probably provide part names and numbers and perhaps manuals that you can use when talking to a machinist.

It does appear that this model is a "panel saw" so you might have better luck with those search terms.